# If $\phi:G\longrightarrow A^{\times}$ is a nontrivial character, why is $H^1(G,A)=0$?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

If $\phi:G\longrightarrow A^{\times}$ is a nontrivial character and $M=A^1$, where $A$ is a ring, why is $H^1(G,M)=0$ if $G$ acts via $\phi$?

This is essentially the claim that Wiles makes on p. 465 of his Fermat paper, in the course of the proof of Prop. 1.2.

Comment: This might be a good time to go back and review our guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Your post is a bare problem statement and is missing important context, which can lead to your post being closed.

Comment: You probably mean that $A$ is a ring and $\phi$ defines the $G$-action on $A$.

Comment: @reuns: yes. I thought this was clear from the context.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $A^1$? In Wiles paper that notation relates to a filtration on the ordinary adjoint representation. Without any context it makes no sense at all.

Comment: @user994373 The X in Wiles's paper is essentially isomorphic to a submodule of a one-dimensional module, so it is essentially the same case. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: In your question you set $M = A^1$. What is $A^1$?